# Pivot/Cross tab results on PHP/SQL query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

Running most recent version of PHP under most recent build of WAMPserver.

Database is SQL Server 2005

Here is the query I am currently running that works. What I want to do is change the output from:

```
CorrectionsCount , Employee  , Date    
1                , Joe       , 02/12/2012
31               , Barbara   , 02/13/2012    
12               , Paula     , 02/16/2012
```

To something like this

```
[EMPLOYEE NAME], 02/12/2012,    02/13/2012,    02/16/2012    
Joe              , 31         , 0              , 0    
Barbara          , 0          , 31             , 0   
Paula            , 0          , 0              , 12
```

Code:

```
<?php

// connect to DSN 
$DP2connect = odbc_connect("DB", "USER", "PWORD") or die ("Could not connect to 

server");

$DP2query = "
SELECT SUM(CorrectionsCount),CorrectionUser,
convert(char(10), DateHourCorrected, 120)
FROM ISIImageCorrections
WHERE DateHourCorrected BETWEEN '$theDate1' AND '$theDate2'
GROUP BY CorrectionsCount,CorrectionUser,DateHourCorrected
";


$DP2result2 = odbc_exec($DP2connect, $DP2query);

odbc_result_all($DP2result2, 'id="results"');
?>
```

$thedate1 and $thedate2 are variables being POSTed to this page by a calendar picker from another PHP page.

UPDATE: I tried running the COALESCE function described below, but it generates a syntax error near the keyword 'FROM' (the second instance of "FROM" in this statement). Am I inputting it properly?

```
$DP2connect = odbc_connect("dp2_database", "DP2", "DP2Express!") or die ("Could not connect to 

server");

$DP2query = 
"WITH T 
AS(
    SELECT CorrectionUser, CorrectionsCount, DateHourCorrected
    FROM ISIImageCorrections
)
SELECT CorrectionUser, 
       COALESCE([02/12/2012], 0) AS [02/12/2012],
       COALESCE([02/13/2012], 0) AS [02/13/2012],
       COALESCE([02/16/2012], 0) AS [02/16/2012],
FROM T
PIVOT(SUM(CorrectionsCount) FOR [Date] IN([02/12/2012], [02/13/2012], [02/16/2012])) AS P";


$DP2result2 = odbc_exec($DP2connect, $DP2query);

odbc_result_all($DP2result2, 'id="results"');
```

Comment: to fix the error, remove the ',' that comes before the `FROM` - for future notice, if someone posts an answer and you have problems with the answer, you can put a comment down below their answer and they will get a notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I am using `SUM`, choose any aggregate function of your liking:

```
WITH T AS(
    SELECT Employee, CorrectionsCount, [Date]
    FROM @yourTable
)
SELECT Employee, 
       COALESCE([02/12/2012], 0) AS [02/12/2012],
       COALESCE([02/13/2012], 0) AS [02/13/2012],
       COALESCE([02/16/2012], 0) AS [02/16/2012]
FROM T
PIVOT(SUM(CorrectionsCount) FOR [Date] 
      IN([02/12/2012], [02/13/2012], [02/16/2012])) AS P;
```